# Bash — check if variable is different from any of many options

Tags: bash, if-statement

If I have the code

```
if [[ this != that && this != another ]]
```

Is there a way to make it sorter? Something like

```
if [[ this !=that && != another ]]
```

Naturally that won’t work, but something like that, that can shorten the conditions.

Comment: If you have many of these, `case` might help.

Comment: My problem isn’t exactly that they’re many, but that the condition they have to check against is a bit long.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With bash, you can use regular expressions inside `[[`:

```
if [[ ! this =~ ^(that|another|this\ one)$ ]]; then
   # do something
fi
```

The precedence of the `!` (not) operator might be confusing if you're used to any other programming language. Also, beware: *do not put the regular expression in quotes*. If you do, it is no longer a regular expression.